# Machine Man / Batman driving awkwardly

Tags: dc, batman

[Machine Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebula_Mask_Machine_Man), in his TV series, and Batman in *[The Dark Knight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_(film))*, drive their vehicles (Car / Batmobile) faced down. What is the reason for this? Machine Man always drives his car facing down but Batman converted his Batmobile and somehow in the process made him facing down.

Comment: I don't remember machine man being in The Dark Knight. Film or comic?

Comment: For the Batmobile, it's answered in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18674/23243

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just another application of the [Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) (warning: TV Tropes will consume all available time).